# R caret package, how do I tune the intercept and slope in lm?

Tags: r, r-caret, lm

I'm attempting to use the R caret package to perform 5-fold cross-validation of a linear regression model. I'm new to machine learning, but I expected that with each "repeat", a new slope and intercept would be fit to the "training" data set. However by default,  the slope and intercept are held constant for all repeats, and the testing just appears to be putting out new RMSE and Rsquared with each repeat. Is there a way to allow tuning of the intercept?

Here is my code:

```
regressControl  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                            number = 5,
                            repeats = 5)    

regress         <- train(y ~ x,
                   data = myData,
                   method  = "lm",
                   trControl = regressControl)
regress
```

The output looks like this:

```
Linear Regression 

54 samples
 1 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 45, 44, 42, 42, 43, 43, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE        Rsquared 
  0.01162334  0.9614908

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE

regress$finalModel
Call:
lm(formula = .outcome ~ ., data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     x  
   -0.03054      0.01690
```

Comment: The slope and intercept are not being held constant. You are only looking at `regress$finalModel`, which picks the single best sub-model according to your RMSE criteria. Both the slope and the intercept are definitely being "tuned" for each fold. You could doctor the function to show you each new slope and intercept value for each sub-model, but that would be a bit academic.

Comment: To add to what @Chrisss has said, you can look at the RMSE and Rsq for each iteration using regress$resample, which proves to you that a different model is fit for each iteration.

Comment: My concern was that the slope and intercept has always come out the exactly the same (down to many decimal places), as when I generate run the standard "lm" on the full dataset, regardless of how I vary the resampling parameters. This just seems unlikely if it is truly tuning with each fold. regress$resample provides the RMSE and Rsquared for each resampling but not the slopes and intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and change the tuneGrid parameter it is TRUE by default

```
regressControl  <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                            number = 5,
                            repeats = 5)    

regress         <- train(y ~ x,
                   data = myData,
                   method  = "lm",
                   trControl = regressControl),
                   tuneGrid = expand.grid(intercept = TRUE)
regress
```